# $f(x)=\mu([a,x]\cap E )$. Calculate $f'$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

[image]

This is a question from an analysis exam. While I know how to show absolute continuity I have no idea how to calculate $f'$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus or Lebesgue differentiation theorem?

Comment: Just notice that $f(x) = \int_a^x \chi_E d\mu$